# Elasticsearch reindex does not appear to use new index template

Tags: elasticsearch, reindex

This was working under version 6.8 of ES but now that I have upgraded to 7.10 the reindex operation appears to completely ignore the template associated with the dest index.

Logs show that the template was applied when the index was created:
`authentication_2019.09.02] creating index, cause [auto(bulk api)], templates [authentication_template]`

here is the mapping:

```
elasticsearch@secesprd02:~$ cat json/indexes/authentication-index-tmpl.json
{
  "index_patterns": ["authentication*", "auth_*" ],
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 2
  },
  "mappings": {
      "dynamic": false, 
      "properties": {       
          "ISODATE": {
          "type": "date"
        },
        "MESSAGE": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 25
            }
          }
        },
        "assoc_ip": {
          "type": "ip"
        },
        "city": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "ignore_above": 25
        },
        "country": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "ignore_above": 5
        },
        "data": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 25
            }
          }
        },
        "event_class": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "ignore_above": 25
        },
        "event_source": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "ignore_above": 256
        },
        "event_type": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "ignore_above": 20
        },
        "group": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "ignore_above": 20
        },
        "level": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "location" : {
          "type" : "geo_point"
        },
        "service": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 25
            }
          }
        },
        "session_id": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "ignore_above": 50
        },
        "src_city": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "ignore_above": 50
        },
        "src_country": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "ignore_above": 10
        },
        "src_ip": {
          "type": "ip"
        },
        "status": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "ignore_above": 10
        },
        "user": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "ignore_above": 50
        }
      }
  }
}
```

in particular this shows that 'dynamic' is set to false but a search of the index shows everything is copied not just the fields in the template.

Here is what is turning up in the dest index (it is identical to what is in the source). [slightly redacted]  This data is from when I was starting out and I want to clean it up.

```
        "_source": {
          "user": "xxx691",
          "status": "success",
          "srcip": "130.216.yy.yyy",
          "service": "WEBSSO",
          "event_type": "authentication",
          "event_source": "ec-kerberos",
          "SOURCE": "s_loghost",
          "PROGRAM": "krb5kdc",
          "PRIORITY": "info",
          "PID": "1937",
          "MESSAGE": "AS_REQ (4 etypes {18 17 16 23}) 130.216.yy.yy: ISSUE: authtime 1567391809, etypes {rep=16 tkt=16 ses=16}, xxxx691@WEBSSO.AUCKLAND.AC.NZ for krbtgt/WEBSSO.AUCKLAND.AC.NZ@WEBSSO.AUCKLAND.AC.NZ",
          "LEGACY_MSGHDR": "krb5kdc[1937]: ",
          "ISODATE": "2019-09-02T14:36:49+12:00",
          "HOST_FROM": "10.5.144.1",
          "HOST": "10.5.144.19",
          "FACILITY": "auth",
          "DATE": "Sep  2 14:36:49"
        }
```

Update: I have now tried creating the dest index independent of the reindex operation but this makes no difference.

I tried adding a script to the reindex to explicitly remove/rename fields but the script seems to be ignored.  I know it gets compiled because it found syntax errors ;)

Any clues as to what might be going on?

Comment: So what you're saying is that your index template only has a handful of fields defined, yet during reindex new fields get added to the mapping even though dynamic is set to false? Can you share your index template?

Comment: exactly.  Edited to include full mapping and a sample doc

Comment: In the end I worked around this by writing my own client side reindex instead of calling the server side one in the ruby API or the client in the  extension api.   about 10 lines of code.